# Pine Editor: How to Call Value from a NonStandard Indicator into a Script

Tags: pine-script, indicator

I am trying to use a value from one non built-in indicator in my script. I cannot reverse engineer the indicator as the particular indicator has a locked script, but an output has is available as: "signal" (which is a value of either 0,1,2 or 3). This can be seen in the 'Data' sidebar.

The indicator I am referring to is: Tool: Chop and Trade Zones (v2)
when loading it to my chart it displays as: Tool: Chop and Trade Zones - Pro

I came across a similar question here

and tried the proposed solution:
https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-use-one-scripts-output-as-an-input-into-another

*How can I use one script’s output as an input into another?
Use the following in your code:
ExternalIndicator = input(close, "External Indicator")*

But this does not work.
I even tried using the example "Awesome Oscillator" example and cannot get the variable to work
(when i change "close" in the above function to the relevant variable name I get the error: Undeclared identifier `ao` (when trying with the awesome oscillator, and Undeclared identifier `signal` when trying with the abovementioned indicator).

Any helps on being able to use another indicator value within my script is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, visit the site below to know [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Read this [article](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000474048/)